# C++: template function with table argument

Tags: c++, templates

I have these methods:

```
/// PRIVATE
template <class T> void Setting::saveData(___uint16 address, const T &value)
{
    T *pValue = (T*)&value;
    this->pStorage->write(address, (void *)pValue, sizeof(value));
}

/// PUBLIC
void Setting::saveCoordinatorAddr(const ___uint8 *pAddr)
{
    saveData(ADDR_COORDINATOR_ADDR, **XXXX**);
}
```

The saveCoordinatorAddr() method is used to save a table defines like that :

```
___uint8 CoordinatorAddr[8];
```

So, what do I write instead **XXXX** (ex: saveData(ADDR_COORDINATOR_ADDR, pAddr);) ?

Thanks guys

Comment: Do you know the actual size of `pAddr`? It's pretty unclear what you're asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
/// PUBLIC
void Setting::saveCoordinatorAddr(const ___uint8 *pAddr)
{
    saveData(ADDR_COORDINATOR_ADDR, **XXXX**);
}
```

To:

```
/// PUBLIC
void Setting::saveCoordinatorAddr(const ___uint8 (&pAddr)[8])
{
    saveData(ADDR_COORDINATOR_ADDR, pAddr);
}
```

This will mean that the deduced T is of the correct type that matches the size required.